# Pagination dosen't work on my React Admin List?

Tags: reactjs, api, rest, react-admin

I have an issue with the library marmelab React Admin,

I'm using an Api built by my compagny to fetch data and view them into list. Api support pagination query, it work pretty good on Postman. But on my application, when i press next or any other page, nothing change on my List. Even when i click on filter nothing change.

Someone can help me with this ?

Thanks

Comment: Please add more details: what dataProvider you're using, which parameters your API expects for pagination and filtering.

Comment: Also please show us what you're doing in that list.